# Is there a way to execute an action in datatable on each row loading?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm working with JSF pages, using primefaces, and I've got a problem: I need to execute an action for every time a new row is loaded in a datatable.

In short, for example, every entity, data from which used to be displayed in a row, has a collection of objects, that I need to divide into two collections.

So, any ideas, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @kolossus, solve this problem like this:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
    <p:column style="display: none;">
        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="..."/>
    </p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special need be done really. You can take each definition of column content as a definition of row content. Take the following example

```
  <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
     <p:column headerText="Id">
         <h:outputText id="aText" value="#{car.id}">
            <f:event name="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.execute}"/>
         </h:outputText>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Year">
          <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
     </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Brand">
          <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Color">
          <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
      </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

The `<f:event/>` tag there will execute `bean.execute` everytime `aText` is rendered to the page (read: for every row).

---

**Note:** You should know that the sample above will execute  **everytime** rows in the table are being rendered: first-time page visits, ajax updates and page refreshes

Comment: Thanks for yor reply, @kolossus!
You fave me the idea to make an invisible column and add to it an <f:event ..> tag.
Tahks a lot, again!